# Condensing a huge number?

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm trying to find out ways to display a huge number in terms of power, but in vain (or maybe my brain is hibernating). For example, if

result = 0.00012845, it should be displayed as 12.845 x 10^-5 or if
result = 1284569, it should be displayed as 1284.569 x 10^3 and so on.

Comment: Use `ToString("E")` and it will display `1.284500E-004`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to work out what rules you are using to determine what your exponent is and where your decimal separator is. The "E" format specifier will kind of do what you want but it will use the scientific standard of having the significand be between greater than or equal to one and less than ten which is not a rule you are following...

Comment: The rule seems to be 'condense!'; it seems to lack the rule 'in a unified way'..

Comment: Basically to answer this question you need to tell us what your rules are for choosing the exponent and the significand. Also I note you haven't actually given an example of the sort of hugeness of number you are wanting to look at. This might be useful information to have. eg if it is a three thousand decimal digit long number then how it is stored may influence the answer.

Comment: @TaW except in the second example when "1284.569 x 10^3" is longer than "1284569" so isn't really condensed. :)

Comment: Good catch but not necessarily a contradiction: There is no real and solid rule..

Comment: I understand I might have missed out on some specifications, so I apologize. We learnt about c# approximately 5 days ago, and were given an assignment to do. Also, my programming skills are extremely rusty (was good at java once upon a fairytale), so naturally, 10 or so downvotes on this question is probably expected.
Thank you for the answering my question though! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Double.ToString("E") to get scientific notation in the form of 123.456E7 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierExponent)

Then you can go one step further and use String.Replace to replace "E" with " x 10^".

It would look something like this...

```
string myString = myDouble.ToString("E").Replace("E", " x 10^");
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've never tried it before and I'm surprised that this works, try this code on a console application:

```
double number = 0.00012845;

        while(number > 0.0001)
        {
            number /= 10;
        }

        Console.Write(number);

        Console.ReadKey();
```